# Python Smallest Possible Positive Float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got bored and used this code:

```
n=1
while n != 0:
    print(str(n)+" / 2 = "+str(n/2))
    n/=2
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print("Value of "+str(i)+"e-324:")
    print(float(str(i)+"e-324"))
```

The output implies that 5e-324 is the smallest positive float possible.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [sys.float_info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) says that this is the way to get the smallest possible float:

```
>>> math.ulp(0.0)
5e-324
```

The value of `sys.float_info.min` (part of a previous answer that I deleted) gives the smallest normalized float, a much bigger value.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this problem is to look into the details of how floats work, e.g. on Wikipedia. Acknowledging that python uses IEEE double precision floats on most platforms, and slogging through the relevant bits of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples:

> +2<sup>−1022</sup> × 2<sup>−52</sup> = 2<sup>−1074</sup> ≈ 4.9406564584124654 × 10<sup>−324</sup> (Min. subnormal positive double)

Comment: I wonder why they show that amount of digits. More than necessary, and far fewer than it actually has.

Comment: @KellyBundy technically it has a finite decimal representation with ~1000 significant digits, give or take. They only provided 17 of those, which seems (a) like a reasonable compromise, and (b) enough to correctly reproduce normal numbers in binary, not that this number is normal

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Maybe I'm too used to Python's as-short-as-possible representation. It's 751 significant digits, btw.

Comment: @KellyBundy. For a sufficiently broad definition of "~", I nailed it :)